# Featherlight getting value of input text box after close?

Tags: featherlight.js

I've uploaded an example file (html + js) for a form which is called by FeatherLight. You can download the example from here:
https://ufile.io/f9gpo

The problem is that after closing the FeatherLight lightbox, i have a trigger for "afterClose" and i'm trying to print the value of the input text box, but i get "undefined" instead of the actual value.

How can i access that value after closing the FeatherLight lightbox?.
Thank you.

Comment: For next time: jsfiddle / codepen / ... are more practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the trigger `beforeClose` instead... The `persist` option also allows to have a persistent form.

Comment: it did the job, but problem remains. it seems like you can't set / get values of input boxes after they were opened with Featherlight once. I'll post a different example later on (can't post a new question for 90 minutes so far)

Comment: I've opened a different topic about the behavior. You may see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198106/cant-change-get-value-of-input-after-being-opened-with-featherlight